# Python, Change String of Words

Tags: python

I need some help with my code. I am currently coding hangman in python and given a word and letter, I am trying to make the word in to underlines, and show the correctly guessed letter. 
An example would be given the input ('headphones', ['e', 'd']) would return '_e_d____e_'.

```
result = ''
matches = 0
for i in past_guesses:
    if i in word:
        result += i
    else:
        status += '_'
        matches += 1

return result
```

This is what I have tried, but I keep getting 'ed' as the return. Anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` clause, you're appending an underscore to `status`, not `result`.

EDIT: As Julien pointed out, you're looping over the wrong thing.

If your intent is to produce a string that is as long as the original word, then your loop should execute as many times as the length of the word; i.e. you should be looping over the letters of `word`, not `past_guesses`.

To put it another way, if the user has made three guesses, then your function will return a string of only three letters, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: Right, cause in my case its just as long as the past guess, which in this case would only be 2 letters. Thank you for the clarification and help.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of computers is the same as the logic of humans, you need to check if the letters of your word are in the guesses, not the other way around. And you need to update `results` in both cases...

```
result = ''
for i in word:
    if i in past_guesses:
        result += i
    else:
        result += '_'
```

or more pythonic: `"".join(i if i in past_guesses else '_' for i in word)`

Comment: Right, python first checks if 'i' is in word then continues on to the loop. Whereas, in my code it checks if 'i' is in the guess, which would only result in 1 iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic template for a hangman game. Create a `board` that is the `len` of `word`. We will replace the indexes of this `board` if our `guess` is in `word`. We can also create a list `guessed` to append all of the guesses to so we can track if an entry has already been attempted.

From here we can set up a `while` loop that will break once our `board == word`. Take the `guess` from user, then check if it has already been used. If not then we evaluate if that `guess` is in `word`, using list comprehension to retrieve the indexes. If any indexes are found we will convert `board` to  list then replace them and then `.join()` board back to a string, if not we can print `guess not in word`.

Before we continue to the next loop we can append our `guess` to our `guessed` list and print our up to date `board`

```
word = 'headphones'
board = '_' * len(word)
guessed = []

while board != word:
    guess = input('Enter letter: ')
    if guess in guessed:
        print(f'{guess} has already been used!')
    else:
        lst = [i for i, v in enumerate(word) if v == guess] 
        board = list(board)
        if lst:
            for i in lst:
                board[i] = guess
        else:
            print(f'{guess} was not in the word.')

    guessed.append(guess)
    board = ''.join(board)
    print(board)

print('Congratulations, the word was {word}!')
```